# Is it possible for a user to have more than one accounts in the same SE?

Tags: support, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

Is it actually possible (and allowed ) for the same user to have more than one account in the same stack exchange? I think  should be possible as one could simply have a different email and login from that.But this would mean that he has an unfair advantage over the others as for example,  he can vote twice for the same post.

Comment: Using a second account to vote for oneself - is strictly forbidden. Users get banned for that.

Comment: If you have accounts from different e-mail addresses, you can ask for these accounts to be merged.

Comment: How can I merge two accounts

Comment: [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/168333)